# How can I use auto incremental column to generate a fixed length string in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using Postgresql 11 and I have a string column which is fixed 8 length digital number. The value should be in sequence `00000001`, `00000002` etc. I know Postgresql supports `SEQUENCE` column but how can I make it to be a fixed length string?

One solution is to use two SQL, one is to `insert` the row with an SEQUENCE column (which is integer), the other sql is to update the row based on the SEQUENCE column value to make it to be e.g. `00000001`.

I also come cross LPAD function but not sure whether it works for this case.

Comment: Is this maybe what you're looking for? `CREATE SEQUENCE seq1;` and then `SELECT lpad(nextval('seq1')::text,8,'0');`

Comment: There is no need to _store_ the number that way. You can always format it when you _display_ the value. Do you want that value to be generated automatically when you insert new rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a standard sequence and then use `lpad` to pad the zeros you want:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq1;

SELECT lpad(nextval('seq1')::text,8,'0');

   lpad   
----------
 00000001
```

**EDIT**: as mentioned in the comments by @a_horse_with_no_name, `to_char()` is a neat alternative

```
SELECT to_char(nextval('seq1'), 'FM00000000');
 to_char  
----------
 00000001
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=76e2cf1abe26f255e6df06d7223469e6)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for the hint! It's really nice when by answering a question I am the one who learns a new trick :-D cheers

Comment: `lpad()` turns out to be slightly faster than `to_char()` ;)

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't store the number that way to begin with. Create an identity column and use `to_char()` or `lpad()` when *displaying* the value. If you need this a lot, you can create a view to avoid writing the expression all the time:

```
create table the_table
(
  id integer generated always as identity (maxvalue 99999999),
  ... other columns
);


create view the_table_with_formatted_id
as
select lpad(id::text, 8, '0') as formatted_id, 
       ... other columns
from the_table;
```

---

Another option is to use the sequence in a default value for a `text` column:

```
create sequence the_table_id_seq;
create table t
( 
  id text default lpad(nextval('the_table_id_seq')::text, 8, '0'), 
  ... other columns ...
);
```

Unlike the `identity` column, the above does not prevent INSERTs bypassing the sequence and storing e.g. `abcdefgh` into that column. If you want to ensure it's a strictly numeric (but formatted) value, using an identity columns is a much better choice.